# show that for Pareto distribution mean deviation about mean cannot exceed the standard deviation

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

show that for Pareto distribution  mean deviation about mean cannot exceed the standard deviation

Comment: Hi Arnab, this smells an awful lot like a homework question to me, and this isn't a site for other people to just solve your homework questions. Could you possibly discuss what you've tried so far, what sort of options you think you have, and what sort of questions you've done around this one?

Comment: You will not be able to show this for $\alpha \lt 1$ as there would be an infinite mean. But you might show it by generalising to all random variables with a finite mean (and perhaps a finite standard deviation).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the distribution has a mean and standard deviation (not all Pareto distributions do):

Let $X$ be a random variable from the distribution, and $Y=|X-E[X]|$.

Then $ E[(Y-E[Y])^2] = E[Y^2] - E[2\,Y\,E[Y]] + E[(E[Y])^2] = E[Y^2] - (E[Y])^2 \ge 0$ so $E[Y^2] \ge  (E[Y])^2$ and so $\sqrt{E[Y^2]} \ge  E[Y] $.

This proves the assertion since $\sqrt{E[Y^2]}$ is the standard deviation of $X$, while $E[Y]$ is the mean absolute deviation of $X$ about the mean of $X$.